# edit autocomplete settings in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, autocomplete, intellisense

Where can i change the settings of autocomplete / intelliSense in visual studio 2010?
- Suggestions list shows for every character typed, somewhat annoying.
- Spacebar(and a lot of other characters) is commiting suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

to edit the auto-complete / intellisense settings in visual studio 2010.
go to Tools -> Options... -> TextEditor -> C# -> IntelliSense

Default settings will always show a suggestion list for every character you type, and pressing spacebar (as well as a lot of other stupid characters) will always "commit" the current selected suggestion. Turn that dumb stuff off. Ofcourse you want the Enter key as the "commit" action, to do that just remove all characters and uncheck "Commited by pressing the spacebar".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/fcf2zk43(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: really that stupid spacebar commiting is annoying [was annoying :-) ]

Answer (score 0):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> IntelliSense

[image: screenshot]